# How to get sum of children and check if it's equal to root?

Tags: javascript

I was solving a problem at leetcode and it was to get if the root equals the sum of children
this is my code

```
    var checkTree = function (root) {
  root[0] = root[0] === undefined ? 0 : root[0];
  root[1] = root[1] === undefined ? null : root[1];
  root[2] = root[2] === undefined ? null : root[2];
  if (root[0] === root[1] + root[2]) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

checkTree([10, 4, 6]);
```

but when i submit it says it is wrong.

here's the link to the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/root-equals-sum-of-children/

Comment: Why do these checks instead of simple `return root[0] === root[1] + root[2]`?

Comment: you're right I should be doing this but the problem is not solved yet.

Comment: Check @Pratik answer. In a nutshell, there's a hidden part of the solution transforming array `[10, 4, 6]` into a TreeNode structure, which actually is an object. So to access root's value (10), you should actually execute `root.val` statement, and not just `root[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EXPLANATION**

So the problem gives you the definition of the node like this

```js
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * function TreeNode(val, left, right) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.left = (left===undefined ? null : left)
 *     this.right = (right===undefined ? null : right)
 * }
 */
/**
```

Inside checkTree function you receive `root` as a parameter.
This `root` is nothing but a instance of `TreeNode` which will look something like

`root = {val: 35, right: null, left: null}`

`right` and `left` can point to other TreeNodes as well.

Question gives you a `root` node, `left` node and a `right` node

`root.left` points to a node which is your `left` node and `root.right` points to a node which is your `right` node

So suppose if my tree is something like this

[image]

`root` is **5**, `root.left` would be node **3** and `root.right` would be node **1**

`root.left.val` is equal to **3** and `root.right.val` is equal to **1** & `root.val` is **5**

So if addition of both `root.left.val` & `root.right.val` is equal to `root.val` the `return` statement would return `true` else `false`.

So in this case it would return false as **3 + 1** is **not equal** to **5**

And this is how below code would work :)

```js
var checkTree = function(root) {
    return root.left.val + root.right.val === root.val
};
```

Comment: I saw this solution but couldn't understand it. If you can explain it I'll be thankfull and thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks alot dude. Your explanation is so clear and simple. I appreciate it and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I was allmost there but did not know i need `.val` behind left and right too.
So i was at

```
return root.val == (root.left + root.right);
```

As the `.val` was not in the definition for right and left.